# Dojo DateTextBox starting on monday

Tags: dojo, calendar

I was using DateTextBox in my project but I would the calendar start on Monday instead of Sunday.
Is there a way to do such thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

it depends on the locale as defined by your [config](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/dojo_config/)  Dojo has a table which will choose the first day of the week based on country information in the locale.